# imagecreatefromjpeg() function in php

Tags: php, function, image.createimage

I'm using imagecreatefromjpeg() function to merge two pictures..

now the problem which I'm facing is that when I use the pictures from my server, it works perfectly and when I use pictures from some other website, it doesn't work.

For example: when I use this PHP file http://coolfbapps.in/test/merger.php with function

```
 imagecreatefrompng('http://coolfbapps.in/test/1.png');
```

It works perfectly fine as the image is at my own server

but when I alter this function and put the link of an image which is not on my server,

for example:

```
imagecreatefrompng('http://www.businesseconomics/Test.png');
```

it doesn't work. (the image file is not on my server)

please suggest me an alternative to this function or a solution as I want to use this with Facebook apps..

Comment: It smells permission problem. Check http://graph.facebook.com/erkintek/picture&type=large

Comment: no.. i dont think its permission problem b'coz i tried getting images of frnds and it shows them..

Comment: when you try from firefox, you can download image because you'r logged, when you try with php, php is not logged! If your friends allow photo to be shown anyone, I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP Function `copy()` to save the image on your Server.